# ensure that global variable availability inside of callback invoked via apply inside of jQuery function

Tags: javascript, scope

**simple example:**

the plugin code

```
(function($){
    var app = {};

    app.callfunction = function(fn,args)
    {
        //tried so far: window,null,this
        fn.apply(null,args);
    };

    $.app = app;

}(jQuery));
```

the example usage of the plugin

```
$(function(){

    var config = {
        url:'http://example.com',
        loggedIn: false
    };

    for(var prop in config){
        window[prop] = config[prop];
    }

    $.app.callfunction(function(a,b){
        if(!loggedIn){ //Reference error: `loggedIn` is not defined
            return false;
        }
        return a+b;
    },[5,6]);

});
```

I don't understand why `loggedIn` is undefined. even trying to access `window` it says that too is undefined. can someone explain to me why this happens? is there a way for me to store a reference to the window inside of the plugin IEFE?

Comment: Have you tried `$` as the context in your apply?

Comment: @AR7 yes. i've literally tried everything. if i call the callback with paranthesis instead of apply, it works fine, however there is no way to unpack the arguments in this manner without eval which is dumb. god i hate this shitty language.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r3wt/gbu2yc3m/9/ possible solution, but flawed.